# Python regex for matching \\\\192.168.1.1\\Hello\\There\\How\\Are\\You

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to make a regex in Python to match the string

> \\192.168.1.1\\Hello\\There\\How\\Are\\You

The string should start with **\\\\**

The part after **\\**, **'192.168.1.1'** is an IP addres.

The '**\\Hello**' part after the IP address can repeat multiple times (unknown).

So far I've got this

> ^\\\\\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$

Comment: So why tag c# if this is not C#?

Comment: Well I thought it'd be similar. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a group which contains the `\` and the text and specify that it occurs one or more times:

```
(\\\w+)+
```

All together:

```
\\\\\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}(\\\w+)+
```

With double `\\`:

```
\\\\\\\\\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}(\\\\\w+)+
```

Comment: @Singhal2 - make sure there are not trailing spaces. Tested both on regex101 and pythex

Comment: This is the Pythex link to your regex  http://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%5C%5C%5C%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D(%5C%5C%5Cw%2B)%2B&test_string=%5C%5C%5C%5C192.168.1.1%5C%5CHello%5C%5Cthere%5C%5Chow%5C%5Care%5C%5Cyou&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: The example in your question states a single "\" between words... just replace each "\\" (single "\") with "\\\\" (double "\\"). See update

Comment: Didn't realise that I needed \\ for every \. Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: @Singhal2 - as "\" needs to be escaped by "\\" when you want the character itself then yap :) Glad I could help

Comment: @Singhal2 No need to use double backslashes in the pattern defined with a **raw** string literal, `r'\d'` = `'\\d'`. Also, you must escape dots outside of character classes to match literal dots.